# Database level permission to a user using other user

Tags: sql, sql-server-2012, permissions

I have 2 database users called `SQLUser1` and `SQLUser2`.  How can I `grant INSERT permission` to `SQLUser2` at database level using `SQLUser1`?

After reading about database membership roles,  I think I can achieve the solution by playing with memberships of SQLUser1. Can it be solved by giving db_securityadmin and db_accessadmin to SQLUser1?How can I control permissions of one user by another user in database level?

Any help appreciated.

Thanks,
Deeps

Comment: What you mean by `using SQLUser1`?

Comment: It is just a random identifier which help me to state the problem.

Comment: SQLUser1 should have the ability to set database level permissions for SQLUser2.

Comment: You should remove that part `using SQLUser1`. It adds confusion to your question. essentially you are trying to know `how to grant some permission to a user`

Comment: I meant that I have to make a user(not sa) who is capable of granting permission to another user in database level.  Is it clear now?  If it is I can edit the question.  Thank your valuable comment.  I did not know that it is confusing.  I don't think "how to grant some permission to a user" will be enough.  I hope my question is clear now.

Comment: In that case, check my answer below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You must grant all/specific privilege to SQLUser1 `with grant option` as `sa` (sys admin or other higher privileged user). Then SQLUser1 will become eligible to grant privilege to SQLUser2 as outlined below

```
GRANT ALL TO SQLUser1 WITH GRANT OPTION
```

You need not to assign `ALL` privilege to SQLUser1. Even SQLUser1 can have only `INSERT` permission but `WITH GRANT OPTION` make him eligible to grant the same permission to other user.

Then as SQLUser1 grant specific privilege to SQLUser2

```
GRANT INSERT TO SQLUser2
```

You can do the above mentioned steps using GUI (SSMS) as well.

For more information on `GRANT` see [HERE](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178569.aspx)

Comment: This is exactly what I meant.  Still I am not sure how to do it with SSMS.  SQLUser1 has INSERT permission with WITH GRANT OPTION (sorry to mention that earlier). When I login as SQLUser1 I can not see SQLUser2 in SSMS.

Comment: @user1598776, you need not to do it in SSMS only. You can just run those command and see if it works. Run those command -> login as user2 and try inserting. that will be a good test as well.

Comment: @user1598776, WITH GRANT OPTION doesn't necessarily means that user1 will be able to view all users. It depends on what privilege user1 has. Also, don't forget to accept the answer if it helped.

Answer (score 0):

you need to use a user which is db_owner.

Select the user2 and click Properties, then user mappings... using SQL Server Management Studio.